# Where is the source code for <jdk>/jre/lib/deploy.jar?

Tags: java, java-web-start

Where is the source code for /jre/lib/deploy.jar?

I have the source code for other jars like rt.jar (in /src.zip) but not deploy.jar.

I need it to debug webstart.
I'm using 1.6 on Windows if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the JDK source code, which isn't bundled in the usual installation.

Get it [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp), see "Java SE 6 JDK Source Code"